# Show div when scroll to specific ID and after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show a div when user scroll to a specific ID but I want that this div appears only after X seconds since the ID is reached by scrolling.

How could I edit this fiddle to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $("#dvid").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/11/

Comment: Simply add a greater height and your code will work fine `body {
    height: 1200px; ...` for example and probably you will need to setup timeout with `setTimeout` with desired delay before showing the div

Comment: Sorry codtex, maybe I didn't explained correctly in my question. I need that the #div is shown after X seconds after user scrolls to #othdiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did add only a [**setTimeout**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and more height of the body to your code and it seems to work. Play with the snippet and ask in comments if you have any questions.

If you want to do something after some delay you can use `setTimeout` and if you want to do something periodically you can use `setInterval`. These are both javascript functions and not jQuery.

If you want you can see the jQuery's [**.delay()**](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method also

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
  var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
  var delay = 500;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#dvid").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
      }, delay);
    }
  });


  $('#update').on('click', function() {
    delay = $('#delay').val();
  });

  $('#hide').on('click', function() {
    $("#dvid").hide(200);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
  font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#othdiv {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 200);
  /*just wanted this to be pretty :)*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
}

#dvid {
  background-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="delay" value="500">
<button id="update">Update Delay</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<div id="othdiv">
  If you scroll past me, then you'll see the other div.
</div>
<div id="dvid">
  Oh hello! :D
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It seems work but I have some problems when I use it in my real page. I suppose that before the ID that I use to fire the trigger there are some collapsed (bootstrap3) divs and this is causing a wrong interpretation of the scrolltop in the window. So I see that to fire the trigger I must scroll much more down. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Francesco sorry for the late response I was at lunch break. Well a work around will be to do a proper calculation for `topOfOthDiv` variable and consider their height too. You need to play with that, but you just need to provide the right value for `topOfOthDiv`

Comment: I don't know exactly What to do. Can you please show me the code?

Comment: @Francesco Well if you setup a demo fiddle I can have a look, but at this point I cannot give you any code, because I don't know how your code looks right now :)

Comment: I've found that the issue is caused by a part of HTML code inserted before my div to show that is hidden for a specific reason. That's why the height is calculated wrong (but correct in fact maybe...). I'm not able to reproduce a fiddle. I could at least provide a link with the page but I would not show it publically.

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution. I've calculated the height of the hidden div into a variable and then subtracted to topOfOthDiv. It seems work now. Maybe could be a better solution but I don't know how.

Comment: @Francesco this sounds great. I think this is a good solution for your use case and was exactly what I was thinking for. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `setTimeout`

```
var millis = 2000;
setTimeout(function() {
     $("#dvid").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
}, millis);
```

But keep in mind, that this will retrigger everytime you scroll by your "breakpoint". So you should adjust this and clear your timeout first if necessary or use a flag and don't try to show it again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var divIsShown = false;
      var millis = 2000; // 2 seconds
      $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
      var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
      $(window).scroll(function() {
           if(!divIsShown && $(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div
                setTimeout(function() {
                     $("#dvid").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
                     divIsShown = true;
                }, millis);
           }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `setTimeout()` method in your existing function. So just wrap your div.show inside of the setTimeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
    var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        setTimeout(function(){$("#dvid").show(200); }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

This here will show your div 1 second after you scroll to it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/1427/)